# CUDA and pinned (page locked) memory not page locked at all?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, cuda

I try to figure out if CUDA (or the OpenCL implementation) tells the truth when I require pinned (page locked) memory.

I tried `cudaMallocHost` and looked at the `/proc/meminfo` values `Mlocked` and `Unevictable` , both stay at 0 and never go up (`/proc/<pid>/status` reports `VmLck` also as 0). I used `mlock` to page lock memory and the values go up as expected.

So two possible reasons for this behavior might be:

1. I don't get page locked memory from the CUDA API and the cudaSuccess is a fake
2. CUDA bypasses the OS counters for page locked memory because CUDA does some magic with the linux kernel

So the actual question is: Why can’t I get the values for page locked memory from the OS when I use CUDA to allocate page locked memory?

Additionally: Where can I get the right values if not from `/proc/meminfo` or `/proc/<pid>/status`?

Thanks!

System:
Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS; CUDA 6.5; Nvidida Driver 340.29; Nvidia Tesla K20c

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would seem that the pinned allocator on CUDA 6.5 under the hood is using `mmap()` with MAP_FIXED.  Although I am not an OS expert, this apparently has the effect of "pinning" memory, i.e. ensuring that its address never changes.  However this is not a complete explanation.  Refer to the answer by @Jeff which points out what is almost certainly the "missing piece".

Let's consider a short test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DSIZE (1048576*1024)

int main(){

  int *data;
  cudaFree(0);
  system("cat /proc/meminfo > out1.txt");
  printf("*$*before alloc\n");
  cudaHostAlloc(&data, DSIZE, cudaHostAllocDefault);
  printf("*$*after alloc\n");
  system("cat /proc/meminfo > out2.txt");
  cudaFreeHost(data);
  system("cat /proc/meminfo > out3.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

If we run this program with `strace`, and excerpt the output part between the `printf` statements, we have:

```
write(1, "*$*before alloc\n", 16*$*before alloc)       = 16
mmap(0x204500000, 1073741824, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0) = 0x204500000
ioctl(11, 0xc0304627, 0x7fffcf72cce0)   = 0
ioctl(3, 0xc0384657, 0x7fffcf72cd70)    = 0
write(1, "*$*after alloc\n", 15*$*after alloc)        = 15
```

(note that 1073741824 is exactly one gigabyte, i.e. the same as the requested 1048576*1024)

Reviewing the [description](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html) of `mmap`, we have:

> address gives a preferred starting address for the mapping. NULL expresses no preference. Any previous mapping at that address is automatically removed. The address you give may still be changed, unless you use the MAP_FIXED flag.

Therefore, assuming the `mmap` command is successful, the virtual address requested will be fixed, which is probably useful, but not the whole story.

As I mentioned, I am not a OS expert, and it's not obvious to me what exactly about this system call would create a "pinned" mapping/allocation.  It may be that the combination of `MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS` somehow creates a pinned underlying allocation, but I've not found any evidence to support that.

Based on [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/600502/) it seems that even `mlock()`-ed pages would not meet the needs of DMA activity, which is one of the key goals of pinned host pages in CUDA.  Therefore, it seems that something else is providing the actual "pinning" (i.e. guaranteeing that the underlying physical pages are always memory-resident, and that their virtual-to-physical mapping doesn't change  -- the latter part of this is possibly accomplished by `MAP_FIXED` along with whatever mechanism guarantees that the underlying physical pages don't move in any way).

This mechanism apparently does not use `mlock()`, and so the mlock'ed pages don't change, before and after.  However we would expect a change in the mapping statistic, and if we diff the out1.txt and out2.txt produced by the above program, we see (excerpted):

```
< Mapped:            87488 kB
---
> Mapped:          1135904 kB
```

The difference is approximately a gigabyte, the amount of "pinned" memory requested.

Comment: Thanks Robert, this is a really good answer. I wasn't aware that mmap could be used to "pin" memory as well.

Comment: Pinned memory means that the virtual to physical address mapping does not change. MAP_FIXED doesn't do that. It just allows you to choose a virtual address. The physical page that backs it can still be moved around.

Answer (score 6):

Page-locked can mean different things. For user-space applications it usually means keeping the page in memory to avoid a page fault:

"A page that has been locked into memory with a call like mlock() is required to always be physically present in the system's RAM. At a superficial level, locked pages should thus never cause a page fault when accessed by an application. **But there is nothing that requires a locked page to always be present in the same place; the kernel is free to move a locked page if the need arises**." [1]

Note that these locked pages can still be moved around and aren't suitable for I/O device access.

Instead, another notion of page-locked is called pinning. A pinned page keeps the same physical mapping. Drivers that need this typically do it rather directly and bypass locked page accounting. `cudaMallocHost` almost certainly uses the cuda driver to pin the pages in this fashion.

More info at [1] below.

[1] https://lwn.net/Articles/600502/

Answer (score 0):

[os_lock_user_pages](https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules/blob/535.86.05/kernel-open/nvidia/os-mlock.c#L214) is called to pin pages.

The Nvidida driver doesn't count the pinned pages. We can't get the values for the memory.