# What's the equivalent system API implementation to cudaMallocHost

Tags: cuda

Hi I want to allocate pinned memory but not using cudaMallocHost, I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888890/cuda-and-pinned-page-locked-memory-not-page-locked-at-all) and tried to use fixed mmap to emulate 'cudaMallocHost' :

```
data_mapped_ = (void *)mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd_, 0);
if(munmap(data_mapped_, sb.st_size) == -1) {
    cerr << "munmap failed" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

data_mapped_ = (void *)mmap(data_mapped_, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, fd_, 0);
```

But this is still not as fast as cudaMallocHost. So what's the correct c implementation of pinned memory?

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages. Your code is not C and CUDA is not C based!

Comment: @Olaf does this matter?

Comment: If you have to ask this, you don't know at least on of the two languages not well enough. I'd recommend you stay with C++/CUDA then. (honestly no offence!)

Comment: @Olaf I believe this question is more about system calls, not the language itself.

Comment: There is no "correct c implementation of pinned memory".  You must use a CUDA C/C++ function call to *properly* pin memory for the intent of its use in CUDA C/C++.  This is because the GPU driver *must be made aware* of the pinned memory.  It's not enough to entirely use C library routines or system routines.  Simply "pinning" memory using a C or system function call does not automatically trigger the processes that the GPU driver will put in place when using CUDA pinned memory, such as avoiding extra memory copying when you invoke `cudaMemcpy*`.

Comment: @RobertCrovella You could make the comment an answer, thank you

Comment: @RobertCrovella And by the way, the reason I am looking for an alternative to cudaMallocHost is that there are always some problems with current linux nvidia drivers (367.18 and 367.27). If I use two GPUs with 367.27 and then it will become much slower unless I replaced all cudaMallocHost with malloc. (it will crash with 367.18 driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CUDA pinned memory (e.g. those pointers returned by `cudaMallocHost`, `cudaHostAlloc`, or `cudaHostRegister`) has several characteristics.  One characteristic is that it is non-pageable and this characteristic is largely provided by underlying system/OS calls.

Another characteristic is that it is *registered* with the CUDA driver.  This registration means the driver keeps track of the starting address and size of the pinned allocation.  It uses that information to decide exactly how it will process future API calls that touch that region, such as `cudaMemcpy` or `cudaMemcpyAsync`.

You could conceivably provide the non-pageable aspect by performing your own system calls.  The only way to perform the CUDA driver registration function is to actually call one of the aforementioned CUDA API calls.

Therefore there is no sequence of purely C library or system library calls that can completely mimic the behavior of one of the aforementioned CUDA API calls that provide "pinned" memory.